# Un-Change color of table cell after radio button click

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a radio button in the very first cell of each row.

Everytime I click on the button the color of the row should change - which it does. But what I want to achieve is that every time I click another radio button, the color of the table cell of the first one should go back to normal - so just the cell is highlighted where the button is clicked.

```
$(".button-class").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").css({"background-color":"#f00"});        
    });
```

This gives the cell the color. How can I "un-color" it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know you are meant to tick the correct answer? If you don't do this, people are not going to be as keen to answer your questions. This is all part of the sophisticated reward scheme that makes this site the best place to find answers to programming questions.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to add a "selected" CSS class to the row you want selected:

```
$(".button-class").click(function(){ 
  $(".selected-class").removeClass("selected-class");
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").addClass("selected-class");
});
```

Here's a sample of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/LNBPq/ Is that more or less what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

**Html**

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="myRadio" class="myRadio" type="radio" />
</td>
<td>
    my row 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <input name="myRadio" class="myRadio" type="radio" />
 </td>
 <td>
    my row 2
  </td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery('.myRadio').bind('change',function(e){
        jQuery('#myTable').find('tr').css('background-color','#fff');
    jQuery(e.target).parents('tr:first').css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yKTN/)

Comment: This one finds every tr element and then applies the background color white, which will not be a good solution.

Comment: @rahul: iam just giving the basic he may use some class named highlight, and do some thing like this jQuery('#myTable').find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

Comment: How can I make this work for just the first cell in each row?